# How is the following program running?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am beginner some very basic  GUI programming using Tkinter module.
I tried running the program, the source code of which  I have copied from another webpage.

```
    from Tkinter import *

    def sel():
        selection = "You selected the option " + str(var.get())
        label.config(text = selection)

    root = Tk()
    var = IntVar()
    R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 1", variable=var, value=1,
              command=sel)
    R1.pack( anchor = W )

    R2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 2", variable=var, value=2,
              command=sel)
    R2.pack( anchor = W )

    R3 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 3", variable=var, value=3,
              command=sel)
    R3.pack( anchor = W)

    label = Label(root)
    label.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

My doubt is that whenever we access global objects inside a function, we have to write

```
    global object_name
```

and then the function works correctly, otherwise the function makes its own copy of the local variable. So why don't we do the same thing here in the definition of the function sel()
I tried adding the following statements to the definition of sel()? Also,

```
    global label
    global var
```

and ran the program, but it made no difference to the working of the program. Why is that?

Comment: You only need `global` when *modifying* a global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need `global` when modifying a global variable.

Consider the following example:

```
myglobal = 'myglobal'

def test_global():
    print myglobal

test_global()

myglobal #output
```

If we take a look at the bytecode we see the variable `myglobal` is loaded as a global:

```
import dis

dis.dis(test_global)

  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (myglobal)
              3 PRINT_ITEM
              4 PRINT_NEWLINE
              5 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

However if we define `myglobal` we see `myglobal` is loaded as a constant, or local variable.

```
import dis

def test_global():
    myglobal = 'mylocal'

dis.dis(test_global)

  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('mylocal')
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (myglobal)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

If we instead try to modify `myglobal` vs simply defining it:

```
myglobal += 'another string'
```

We get an `UnboundLocalError` because we haven't told Python that the variable `myglobal` is a global. Try it like this:

```
global myglobal
myglobal += 'another string'
```

This will work just fine.